# Handling multiple onChange callbacks in a React component

Tags: reactjs

This is how I'm currently handling the scenario with two input boxes. As a separate update method for each one. Can/should this be done with a single `handleChange` method instead?

https://codepen.io/r11na/pen/bZKOpj?editors=0011

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      name1: '',
      name2: ''
    };
  };

  handleChange1(e) {
    this.setState({
      name1: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleChange2(e) {
    this.setState({
      name2: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="row column">
        <Label name={this.state.name1}/>
        <Input onChange={this.handleChange1} />
        <Label name={this.state.name2}/>
        <Input onChange={this.handleChange2} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}

const Label = props => (
  <p {...props}>Hello: <span className="label-name">{props.name}</span></p>
);

const Input = props => (
  <input placeholder="Enter your name" {...props} type="text" /> 
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can/should this be done with a single handleChange method instead?

You can simplify your code like so.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name1: '',
      name2: ''
    };
  };

  handleChange(e, name) {
    this.setState({ [name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="row column">
        <Label name={this.state.name1}/>
        <Input onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e, 'name1') } />
        <Label name={this.state.name2}/>
        <Input onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e, 'name2')  } />
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

[`Example`](https://codepen.io/tarasyuk/pen/WxyPJw?editors=0011)

---

Thanks `@Alik` that mentioned about *eslint* rule [`jsx-no-bind`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#no-bind-or-arrow-functions-in-jsx-props),

> A bind call or arrow function in a JSX prop will create a brand new
>   function on every single render. This is bad for performance, as it
>   will result in the garbage collector being invoked way more than is
>   necessary.

Following this rule you can change your code like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = {
      name1: this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name1'),
      name2: this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name2'),
    }

    this.state = {
      name1: '',
      name2: ''
    };
  };

  handleChange(name, event) {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div class="row column">
        <Label name={this.state.name1}/>
        <Input onChange={ this.onChange.name1 } />
        <Label name={this.state.name2}/>
        <Input onChange={ this.onChange.name2 } />
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

[`Example`](https://codepen.io/tarasyuk/pen/BzVvrr?editors=0010)